# Delete group output socket

Tags: python

I am trying to remove output socket from custom group. Unfortunately, when i use code below only socket outside of the node is removed, but "group_output" node inside the custom group still has said output socket.
[[image: ][1]]

[File if you want to see it for yourself. Selected grouped node and run the script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17QmdrZehe1JYK96tMGtcmt_QWVWITus3/view?usp=sharing)

The code below will try to remove first output socket of selected custom group.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
mat = obj.active_material
nodes = [ n for n in mat.node_tree.nodes if n.select ]
    
if nodes:
    for n in nodes:
        n.outputs.remove(n.outputs[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is answered: when removing output socket you have to refer to the node_tree.outputs and not to the outputs of the node itself. In this case everything works fine